# How to add GET request parameters in AWS canaries

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm new in Cloudwatch synthetics. I want to test my API with Get request with parameters. Please suggest the configuration for adding parameters or provide blue print scripts which uses parameters in get request.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

```
var synthetics = require('Synthetics');
    const log = require('SyntheticsLogger');
    
    const apiCanaryBlueprint = async function () {
        
        // Handle validation for positive scenario
        const validatePositiveCase = async function(res) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                if (res.statusCode < 200 || res.statusCode > 299) {
                    throw res.statusCode + ' ' + res.statusMessage;
                }
         
                let responseBody = '';
                res.on('data', (d) => {
                    responseBody += d;
                });
         
                res.on('end', () => {
                    // Add validation on 'responseBody' here if required. For ex, your status code is 200 but data might be empty
                    resolve();
                });
            });
        };
        
        // Handle validation for negative scenario
        const validateNegativeCase = async function(res) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                if (res.statusCode < 400) {
                    throw res.statusCode + ' ' + res.statusMessage;
                }
            });
        };
        
        let requestOptionsStep1 = {
            'hostname': 'myproductsEndpoint.com',
            'method': 'GET',
            'path': '/test/product/validProductName',
            'port': 443,
            'protocol': 'https:'
        };
        
        let headers = {};
        headers['User-Agent'] = [synthetics.getCanaryUserAgentString(), headers['User-Agent']].join(' ');
        
        requestOptionsStep1['headers'] = headers;
    
        // By default headers, post data and response body are not included in the report for security reasons. 
        // Change the configuration at global level or add as step configuration for individual steps
        let stepConfig = {
            includeRequestHeaders: true, 
            includeResponseHeaders: true,
            restrictedHeaders: ['X-Amz-Security-Token', 'Authorization'], // Restricted header values do not appear in report generated.
            includeRequestBody: true,
            includeResponseBody: true
        };
           
    
        await synthetics.executeHttpStep('Verify GET products API with valid name', requestOptionsStep1, validatePositiveCase, stepConfig);
        
        let requestOptionsStep2 = {
            'hostname': ‘myproductsEndpoint.com',
            'method': 'GET',
            'path': '/test/canary/InvalidName(',
            'port': 443,
            'protocol': 'https:'
        };
        
        headers = {};
        headers['User-Agent'] = [synthetics.getCanaryUserAgentString(), headers['User-Agent']].join(' ');
        
        requestOptionsStep2['headers'] = headers;
    
        // By default headers, post data and response body are not included in the report for security reasons. 
        // Change the configuration at global level or add as step configuration for individual steps
        stepConfig = {
            includeRequestHeaders: true, 
            includeResponseHeaders: true,
            restrictedHeaders: ['X-Amz-Security-Token', 'Authorization'], // Restricted header values do not appear in report generated.
            includeRequestBody: true,
            includeResponseBody: true
        };
        
        await synthetics.executeHttpStep('Verify GET products API with invalid name', requestOptionsStep2, validateNegativeCase, stepConfig);
        
    };
    
    exports.handler = async () => {
        return await apiCanaryBlueprint();
    };
```